# Put imageView in the middle of another

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

I am coding a spirit level with a bullseye using the accelerometer of the device, now I have few questions:

1.My Bullseye Imageview is in the center , how can I set the Center of the ImageView is X:0 Y:0 for the accelerometer?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bullseye"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:contentDescription="Bullseye"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bullseye" />


    ImageView b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bullseye);
    b.setImageResource(R.drawable.bullseye);
```

2.How can I stick my Bubble at start in the middle of the Bullseye and make corners so that the bubble is not allowed to getout of the Bullseye radius?

```
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bubble"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:contentDescription="Bubble"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_bubble"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/yview"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/yview"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    //ImageView Bubble
    mDrawable = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bubble);
    ImageView v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bubble);
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bubble);    


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

        //Zuweisen + Ausgabe
        x -= (int) event.values[0];
        y += (int) event.values[1];

        xview.setText("X: " + x);
        yview.setText("Y: " + y);

        mDrawable.setY(y);
        mDrawable.setX(x);
    }
}
```

[image: Spiritlevel]

i want that the bubble(grey point) stay in the green area and also that the middle of the green area is X:0 Y:0 for the accelerometer.

Comment: Can you please add an example of what you try to achieve?

Comment: i have make an edit.

Comment: I think you have 2 solutions. Both implies to create your own component. #1 Create your own component and use the canvas to draw both images. Redraw everything every time the accelerometer values change. #2 Create you own component containing 2 ImageView (one for the each image). Then you manage the position of the 'bullseye' based on the position of the other image. Update the 'bullseye' position evey time the accelerometer values change. Personally I'd go for the first option